# Use host variables in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to reference host variables in a playbook in combination with "with_items".

My inventory

```
[container]
testcontainer-01.example.org template_name="syslog" ipv4="192.168.1.101"
testcontainer-02.example.org template_name="syslog" ipv4="192.168.1.102"
```

The playbook:

```
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: "{{ item.ipv4 }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ groups['container'] }}"
```

Whenever I run the play I get the following error:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'ipv4'
```

When I ask debug for just `{{ item }}`,without the ipv4 attribute it just says the variable isn't defined.

```
"testcontainer-01.example.org ": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{testcontainer-01.example.org}}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'StrictUndefined' and 'StrictUndefined'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *ipv4* of the host running the play use

```
- debug:
    var: ipv4
```

If you want to list all *ipv4* in *container* use

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[item].ipv4 }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['container'] }}"
```

(not tested)

Answer (score -1):

As posted by Vladimer Botka, the following works.

```
- debug:
        var: "{{ hostvars[item].ipv4 }}"
      with_inventory_hostnames:
        - container
```

For some reason Ansible is still barking at me saying my variable isn't defined. None the less it yields the result that I need. The value of the ipv4 variable is being used in the correct places.

```
ok: [containerhost.example.org] => (item=testcontainer-02.example.org) => {
    "192.168.1.102": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!", 
    "item": "testcontainer-02.example.org"
}
ok: [containerhost.example.org] => (item=testcontainer-01.example.org) => {
    "192.168.1.101": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!", 
    "item": "testcontainer-01.example.org"
}
```

Comment: @Freco: I posted `msg: "{{ hostvars[item].ipv4 }}"`. It's wrong syntax `var: "{{ hostvars[item].ipv4 }}"`, because `"{{ hostvars[item].ipv4 }}"` isn't a variable. It's string. This is also the reason for `"Ansible is still barking at me saying my variable isn't defined"`.